# SQL Concatenate column values and store in an extra column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.2080.9) and I've got a simple task but somehow I am not able to solve it...

I have a little database with one table containing a first name and a last name column

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[person]
(   
    [first_name] [nchar](200) NULL,
    [last_name] [nchar](200) NULL,
    [display_name] [nchar](400) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

and I want to store the combination of first name with an extra whitespace in between in the third column (yes I really have to do that...).

So I thought I might use the CONCAT function

```
UPDATE [dbo].[person]
SET display_name = CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)
```

But my `display_name` column is only showing me the first name... so what's wrong with my SQL?

Kind regards
Sven

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: It is better to use `NVARCHAR(...)` data type for you scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method should work and does work.  The issue, though is that the data types are `nchar()` instead of `nvarchar()`.  That means they are padded with spaces and the last name is starting at position 201 in the string.

Just fix the data type.

In addition, I would suggest that you use a computed column:

```
alter table person add display_name as (concat(first_name, ' ', last_name));
```

This ensures that the `display_name` is always up-to-date -- even when the names change.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0dc3dfdbbcb105544775566c03d89e19) is a db<>fiddle.

As a note:  `char()` and `nchar()` are almost never appropriate.  The one exception is when you have fixed length strings, such as state or country abbreviations or account codes.  In almost all cases, you want `varchar()` or `nvarchar()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, changed the datatype and it worked! I´ve thought about the computed column but this is a one time only job, afterwards the column will be filled by an external script

Comment: @Sven . . . That is actually a good reason to store the value with a pre-computed default.